# Split row elements by character and transform into a vector

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe looking like:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
        ~respondent,           ~selection,
                  1, "Brain/Energy/Sleep",
                  2,    "Energy/Mood/Sex",
                  3,   "Detox/Sex/Stress"
        )
```

I want to count the unique elements in each row, after splitting them at each '/', hence transforming the column `selection` as:

```
selection <- c("selection", "Brain", "Energy", "Sleep", "Energy", "Mood", "Sex", "Detox", "Sex", "Stress")
```

How to perform this using dplyr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new_vec <- 
  df %>% 
  pull(selection) %>% 
  strsplit("/") %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  c("selection", .)

new_vec
 [1] "selection" "Brain"     "Energy"    "Sleep"     "Energy"    "Mood"      "Sex"      
 [8] "Detox"     "Sex"       "Stress"
```

Comment: I used `str_split` instead of `strsplit` and it worked. @cardinal40

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that eliminates duplicate elements in each row. I added a duplicate element in the df to exemplify this.

```
#Your data with a duplicate element
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~respondent,           ~selection,
  1, "Brain/Energy/Sleep/Sleep",
  2,    "Energy/Mood/Sex/Energy",
  3,   "Detox/Sex/Stress/Detox"
)

#Number of columns expected after splitting each row on "/"
ncols_exp<-4

#Getting the distinct values per row (respondent)
df %>%
#Separate each entry in selection as multiple columns
  separate(col = selection,
           into = paste0("Var", 1:ncols_exp),
           sep = "/") %>%
  #Transform data into long format
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Var"),
               names_to = "Var",
               values_to = "Val") %>%
  #Group by "respondent" (each row in the original df)
  group_by(respondent) %>%
  #Get unique elements of the Val column 
  distinct(Val) %>%
  #Pull Val column
  pull(Val) %>%
  #Concatenate the unique values with "selection" as the first entry
  c("selection", .)
```